# How to get data from db and how does the session work in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I am a native PHP programmer and I started learning Laravel a few days ago. I am struggling with how to get data from the database. Usually (in native), I use a query and OOP to connect to the DB and execute queries, but in Laravel it is a little weird and I don't get it.

Example, I want to get data from the database where `user_id = 1`.

#### Last but not least

In vanilla PHP I assigned `auto user_id` without login by using a session, for example:

```php
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  $id = // random function to generate random numbers
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
}
```

I don't know how to do it in Laravel. Please remember that anything will help me so don't hesitate to tell me.

Comment: Laravel has [**great** documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x). Have you read it? [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/topics/laravel) also provides a ton of tutorials on how to get started.

Comment: oh thanks, i will read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the query builder like:

```php
DB::table('table_name')->where('column', $value)->first();
```

Example:

```php
DB::table('users')->where('id', 5)->first();
```

Or you can use `Models` like:

```php
$user = User::find(user_id);
```

Example:

```php
$user = User::find(5);
```

You can find a lot more on the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x)...

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Session::has('user_id')) { // check UserId Exists In The Session
        
} else {
    $id = //rnd function to generate random numbers ;
    Session::put('user_id', $value); // Set Value in Session using put method
}
```

Also find how to get a value from the session in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session).